# Detect os type and set JAVA_HOME

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-14.04, java-home

I would like to detect the os type in a bash script and set JAVA_HOME accordingly.

```
if   [[ $(type -t apt-get) == "file" ]]; then os="apt"
    elif [[ $(type -t yum)     == "file" ]]; then os="yum"
    else
            echo "Could not determine os."
    fi

case "$os" in

        apt)    pushd /etc/ \
                echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/' >> /etc/profile ;;

        yum)    pushd /etc/profile.d/ \
                echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/' >> /etc/profile.d/user_env.sh ;;
esac
```

I have tried this but it seems to not be writing the export to the files.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `$os` actually set to?

Comment: Just a nit: you're checking the package manager type, not the OS type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what purpose the `pushd` serves here, but you don't want the `\` because that would be a continuation of the `pushd` command line and not actually run the echo command.  You want, I think:

```
if   [[ $(type -t apt-get) == "file" ]]; then os="apt"
elif [[ $(type -t yum)     == "file" ]]; then os="yum"
else
    echo "Could not determine os."
fi

case "$os" in
        apt)    echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/' >> /etc/profile ;;
        yum)    echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/' >> /etc/profile.d/user_env.sh ;;
esac
```

If you want to keep the `pushd`, it would be:

```
case "$os" in

        apt)    pushd /etc/
                echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/' >> /etc/profile ;;

        yum)    pushd /etc/profile.d/
                echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/' >> /etc/profile.d/user_env.sh ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thank you and you're right, pushd doesn't serve a purpose there.